# Reorder workspaces in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: workspaces

In previous versions of Ubuntu, where workspaces have been organized vertically, I could reorder workspaces by dragging with mouse. That does not seem to work in new Ubuntu, where workspaces are organized horizontally. Or is there a way?

Comment: For me, Ubuntu on Xorg, I can drag workspaces horizontally into a different order. Will check on Wayland also. - Yes, works on Wayland too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Reorder Workspaces](https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/3685/reorder-workspaces/) Gnome extension to rearrange workspaces with the keyboard. By default the shortcuts are Alt + Up/Down, which is a little unnatural in Ubuntu 22.04, but you can customize them to match the horizontal layout.

If you use the stock Firefox which is installed via snap, don't follow the instructions on the website to install the extension, it won't work. I don't remember how I did it but the two following apps can be installed via the Ubuntu Software app:

[image]

You can use Extension Manager to browse extensions, find Reorder Workspaces and install it.

Answer (score 0):

At this time there is not, sorry.

The Gnome developers made major changes to the code (for good reasons), and older methods of reordering are no longer compatible with the new code.

This has happened in the past, too: Gnome Shell is Open Source, and relies upon volunteer contributors to help develop many features that enhance usability. In the past, volunteers explored the new code and contributed extensions that implemented the feature...but that wasn't immediate in the past and it's not immediate now.

Folks who want to get involved and help Gnome improve are welcome to start their journey at http://www.gnome.org